# Positive Main Effects but Negative Interaction Effect

Tags: multiple-regression, anova, interaction, interpretation

I ran a hierarchical regression on DV "Behave". Two of the main variables I am interested in, "severity" and "RE"(=response efficacy), have positive main effects on the DV. However, the interaction term "Sev_RE" is negatively related with the DV.

(1) How do I interpret these relationships? (See part of the regression table below. The entire hierarchical regression model is also significant) Could it be that one of the other variables is also at play here?

(2) In an attempt to better understand it, I dummy coded "severity" and "RE" (median spilt) and tested it in an ANOVA with the DV, adding all the control variables as covariates. However, the interaction term now is positive. How is this possible? "Severity" and "RE" do have high medians  (4.5 and 4.3 on a 5-point scale) and high means. Could this be a factor? Any interpretation and help on these issues are appreciated! Thank you!!

[image]
[image]

Comment: The two variables combine sub-additively.  Calculate estimated expected values from the model on a grid and make a contour-plot?